# How to launch a local .html file as a pop-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering what I can add to make an .html or .htm file create a pop-up window instead of creating a normal window and load the content in that window. Is there a way to do this? I have no idea, thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is the difference between a "normal" window and a "popup" window? Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `window.open` or `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="www.example.com/example.html" target="_blank">link text</a>
```

target="_blank" makes the link open in a new window, now a new tab